# Grep by block of text\lines

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, shell-scripting

I have the text, that contains some lines. So, i need to make GREP of several lines. For example, i have repeating text and i should GREP get lines, that have this repeating key-words.

```
grep -o "test|test2" textfile
```

My text:

```
123|never for your|test
123421|never for your|test2
123412|never for your|test3
12341|never for your|test4
12311|never for your|test2
123312312|never for your|test
123321312|never for your|test2
```

I should have:

```
123|never for your|test
123421|never for your|test2
123312312|never for your|test
123321312|never for your|test2
```

It works, but it doesn't work how i want. It searchs in text, all words "test" & "test2". But i want to get textblocks, like some pattern, where only after "test" comes "test2". 
Have you got any ideas ?

Comment: test the new code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is http://serverfault.com/questions/827736/grep-of-several-lines-one-by-one question asked in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brief shell script using sed.  Makes a list of line numbers for the second case, and compares against line numbers for the first case.  Prints matching pairs.  Uses the first argument as the file name.  Could easily be extended to take second and third arguments as patterns to match.  Could save as findnext.sh, and run:

```
$ sh findnext.sh testfile
```

Should be quick as it only involves two passes over the file, and has the advantage of being completely portable.

```
#!/bin/sh 
# Line numbers matching test1
mt2=$(sed -ne '/test1/=' < $1 | tr '\n' '/')

for l in $(sed -ne '/test/=' < $1); do
    nextline=$(expr $l + 1)
    [ "${mt2#*$nextline/}" != "$mt2" ] && sed -ne $l,${nextline}p <$1
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try grep -E or egrep.
Please try it like this

```
#this will show lines that have test or test2
    grep -E "test|test2" file
```

If you want to show line that has test and test2 like this test|test2 do this

```
# This will show lines that has test|test2
    grep "test\|test2" file
```

Comment: i have tried, but it doesn't work. i am sorry

Comment: @valeriu can you paste few lines so I can see the pattern

Comment: just a moment. i will pastle it in above text

Comment: yes, it works. but in my text, i have repeat test2. i have tested same commands, that you have written above. i want to have test and test2 together & get lines with this together words/lines

Comment: and i have written, that i have used same command: grep -o "test|test2" textfile

Comment: @valeriu You where doing it correct just use -E instead of the -o so you can use regular expression like test|test2 means "test or test2" with the option -o  you will show only the matching wich is test or test2

Answer (score 0):

`awk` may be your tool for this:

```
awk '/test$/, /test2$/' < block-text-lines.txt
```

the general form is:

```
awk '/start-pattern/, /end-pattern/{command}'
```

But since the command block defaults to print, just the start and end patterns do the trick.

Check out `man awk` or the [Gnu Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) for *way* more detail.

Comment: thanks. but it doesn't work. i have tried all this commands. i have in output repeat test2. but i want to have test2 only before test. and i have test2 before test4. look at my file above

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand.  I run your input through that awk command, above, and get the output your questions says "I should have" in your second quote. Your output has repeated `test2`.

Can you provide a more detailed "after" example of what you are looking to get?

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -A 1 "test$" in.txt | grep -B 1 "test2$"
```

In grep manual

> `-A NUM` Print  NUM  lines  of  trailing  context after matching lines.
>
> `-B NUM` Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.

The command `grep -Pzo ".*test$\n.*test2$" in.txt` also works, but in the manual is "This  is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features."